# Is the Torah only for the living?

Tags: death

Why do we have to cut the tallith of a dead person? Where can we find that the mitsvoth are only for the living?

Answer (score 3):

The customs about  Tsitsit if we need to  cut them for dead person is largely  in Tosfot Niddah 61b. For begining we will see two Gemarot which seems to teach that dead need tsitsit or that this is a shame for him to stress that they cannot make mitsvot.

Gemara Berachot 18a.

> והתניא לא יהלך אדם בבית הקברות ותפילין בראשו וספר תורה בזרועו וקורא ואם עושה כן עובר משום {משלי יז-ה} לועג לרש חרף עושהו
>
> But it has been taught: A man should not walk in a cemetery with tefillin on his head or a scroll of the Law in his arm, and recite the Shema', and if he does so, he comes under the heading of 'He that mocketh the poor blasphemeth his Maker'?
>
> רבי חייא ורבי יונתן הוו שקלי ואזלי בבית הקברות, הוה קשדיא תכלתא דרבי יונתן. אמר ליה רבי חייא: דלייה, כדי שלא יאמרו למחר באין אצלנו ועכשיו מחרפין אותנו.
>
> R' Hiyya and R' Jonathan were once walking about in a cemetery, and the blue fringe of R' Jonathan was trailing on the ground. Said R' Hiyya to him: Lift it up, so that they [the dead] should not say: Tomorrow they are coming to join us and now they are insulting us! He said to him: Do they know so much?

See  Gemara Menachot 41a:

> אמר רב טובי בר קיסנא אמר שמואל כלי קופסא חייבין בציצית ומודה שמואל בזקן שעשאה לכבודו שפטורה מ''ט {דברים כב-יב} אשר תכסה בה אמר רחמנא האי לאו לאיכסויי עבידא בההיא שעתא ודאי רמינן ליה משום {משלי יז-ה} לועג לרש חרף עושהו
>
> R' Tobi B' Kisna said in the name of Samuel, The garments put away in a chest are subject to zizith.
>   Samuel, however, admits that where an old man made it for his shroud it is exempt, for the Divine Law says, Wherewith thou coverest thyself, and this is not intended for an ordinary covering. Nevertheless, when the time comes for its use we should insert fringes in it, on account of the injunction, Whoso mocketh the poor blasphemeth his Maker.

On the other hand, see Gemara Nidda 61b:

> ת"ר: בגד שאבד בו כלאים - הרי זה לא ימכרנו לעובד כוכבים, ולא יעשנו מרדעת לחמור.
>   אבל עושה ממנו תכריכין למת.
>   אמר רב יוסף: זאת אומרת - מצות בטלות לעתיד לבא.
>   א"ל אביי ואי תימא רב דימי: והא א"ר מני א"ר ינאי לא שנו - אלא לספדו, אבל לקוברו - אסור א"ל: לאו איתמר עלה, א"ר יוחנן אפילו לקוברו?
>   ור' יוחנן לטעמיה, דא"ר יוחנן: מאי דכתיב (תהלים פ"ח) במתים חפשי, כיון שמת אדם - נעשה חפשי מן המצות. ‏
>
> Our Rabbis taught: A garment in which kil'ayim was lost may not be sold to an idolater, nor may one make of it a packsaddle for an ass, but it may be made into a shroud for a corpse.
>   R' Joseph observed: This implies that the commandments will be abolished in the Hereafter.
>   Said Abaye (or as some say R' Dimi) to him: But did not R' Manni in the name of R' Jannai state, 'This was learnt only in regard to the time of the lamentations but for burial this is forbidden'? - The other replied: But was it not stated in connection with it, R'  Johanan ruled: Even for burial'?
>   And thereby R' Johanan followed his previously expressed view, for R' Johanan stated: 'What is the purport of the Scriptural text, Free among the dead?
>   **As soon as a man dies he is free from the commandments'**.

Tosfot Nidda 61b:

> ... וא''ת והאיכא לועג לרש שמלבישו בדבר האסור ומראה לו שאין לו עוד חלק במצות כדאמר בהתכלת (מנחות דף מא.) גבי ציצית וההיא שעתא ודאי רמינן ליה משום לועג לרש
>
> Tosfot asked why is it allowed to take for the decease a garment with problem of Shaatnez when the Gemara in Menachot said to give it a garment with tsitsit despit he is exempt, because"Whoso mocketh the poor blasphemeth his Maker".
>
> ופרשב''ם דאין בו איסור ואפילו לחי כי האי גוונא שאין המת נהנה בו
>
> Rashbam answered that there is no profit for the dead (he don't need to stay warm) and in such condition there is no Isur Kilayim even for a live person.
>
> וקשה דהא ציצית נמי אין החי חייב בו אם אין בו הנאת לבישה ומוכרי כסות דפטירי מכלאים פטורים נמי מציצית
>
> If this response is was correct, so why is it needed to give him tsitsit. A live person who wear a garment from which he receives no benefit must not bring tsitsit.
>
> ומפרש רבינו תם דדוקא שייך לועג לרש בציצית משום דשקולה כנגד כל המצות כדנפקא לן במנחות (דף מג:) מוזכרתם את כל מצות ה'
>
> Rabenu Tam answers that the only mitsva for which we say "Whoso mocketh the poor blasphemeth his Maker" is Tsitsit which remember all mitsvot as soon in Gemara Brachot.
>
> והא דאמר בפרק מי שמתו (ברכות דף יח.) אמר ליה (רבי לרבי חייא) דליה לכנפך דלא לימרו למחר באין אצלנו ועכשיו מלעיגים אותנו
>
> But why in Masechet brachot
>
> אע''ג דיש למתים ציצית מכל מקום מה שאנו מראים עצמנו בפניהם מקיימי מצות והם אינם מצווין קרי לועג לרש ואם תאמר
>
> Even though deads wear tsitsit, when we demonstrate that we are making mitsvot and they do not have to do mitsvot.
>
> ועכשיו שאנו רגילין להסיר ציצית מטליתות המתים היאך הוא זה והא אמרינן במנחות (דף מא.) שלכתחילה צריך ליתן ציצית בבגדי המתים משום לועג לרש ובמתי מדבר מצינו בהמוכר הספינה (ב''ב דף עד.) שהיה להם ציצית
>
> Tosfot is astonished by our custom to remove tsitsit from the Talith of deads, it seems to run completely contrary to the Gemara Menachot 41b above cited. This Gemara says that we need to give tsitsit to deads garments, because of "Whoso mocketh the poor blasphemeth his Maker". An additional Gemara which reflecting the fact that deads have tsitsit is in Baba Batra 74a, concerning the generation of those who deceased in desert.
>
> מיהו מהא לא קשה שבכל ט' באב היו נכנסים בקבריהם חיים ולמחר הכרוז יצא הבדלו חיים מתוך המתים כדאיתא באיכה רבתי
>
> The gemara in BB is not really relevant because they was they entered into they graves alive each day of Tish'a Beav.
>
> אבל על מנהגנו יש לתמוה מכח ההיא דהתכלת (מנחות דף מא.) ‏
>
> But our custom is strange considering the Gemara in Menachot.
>
> ואור''י דבימי חכמים שכולן היו לובשים ציצית אם לא היה להם גם במותם לעג גדול היה שדומה כמו שהיו אומרים הואיל ומת אין צריך עוד ציצית אבל עכשיו שאין הכל לובשים ציצית בחייהם אם ישימו ציצית לכולן הוא יותר לועג לרש שבחייו לא קיים ובמותו יקיים
>
> Rabenu Yitschack answered that the Mishna and Gemara period was different from our times. In M&G period, everybody was wearing tsitsit, so to leave a dead without tsitsit is as to say, since he is dead, he needs no more tsitsit. But nowadays, not everybody wear tsitsit when alive. If they give tsitsit to every dead, it is a greater mockery: when alive he was without tsitsit, when he is dead he wears!
>
> ואם ישים למי שהיה לו בחייו ולא למי שלא היה לו יתביישו החיים כדתניא בפ' בתרא (לקמן דף עא.) בראשונה היו מטבילין על גב נדות מתות והיו החיות מתביישות התקינו שיהיו מטבילין על הכל
>
> If they give tsitsit to those who wore tsitsit and not to the others would embarass live person who don't wear tsitsit. ... So our custom is not wrong

ועוד יש קצת סמך למנהגנו שמסירין הציצית ממסכת שמחות (פי''ב) שאבא שאול צוה את בניו קברוהו תחת מרגלותיו של אביו והתירו תכלת מאנפליונו מיהו טעמא של אבא שאול לא נתברר: ‏

> There is an argument for our custom, from Masechet Smachot, Abba Shaul (Ben Botnit)  commanded his sons to burry him at the foots of his father and to remove the Techelet from his garment. But we have no explanation for Abba Shaul theaching.

Tosfot in Berachot 18a added that Rabenu Tam heard in name of Chochme Lautiere (Lorraine) that it is presomptious to show as if they (deads) made 613 (tsitsit = 605 + 8 threads --> 613) mitsvot in their life. Tosfot rejected this explanation. He concluded that we follow the custom described in Masechet Smachot (Abba Shaul). Ritsba was accustomed to hang the tsitsit to the corner, the tsitsit was not seen and not removed.

In Tosfot Baba Batra 74a, Rabenu Chayim Kohen said that we follow the opinion of Rabbi Yochanan in Nidda 61b that mitsvot would be annulled in the future. He made a link between this Machloket about mitsvot in future and the custom to remove tsitsit or not.  RI explained that our custom is entirely congruent with the Gemara in Menachot because there are two steps in the custom.  Firstly we add tsitsiot to the garment as if we say "he was making mitsvot in his life" afterwards they was removed.  RI added that this corresoponds to the  minhag in Germany.

#### Conclusion

> `Where can we find that the mistsvoth are only for the livings ?` ---> Rabbi Yochanan in Gemara Nidda 61b.
>
> `Why do we have to cut the tallith of a dead person`   ---> First possibility: We follow the example of Abba Shaul, not the Gemara in Menachot, second possibility: Nowadays not everybody wear tsitsit in his life, and we avoid to mocke deads who did not wear tsitsit in their life and we avoid to mocke live person who don't wear tsitsit. Maybe that it is the custom of Rabbi Yochanan who stated that in future (tchyat hametim) there is no need to mitsvat tsitsit.   Your link between mitsvot for living and tsitsit is very right according to rav Chayim Kohen (in Tosfot AZ it's written in name of Rav Yehuda).

I hope to add explanations from Rishonim later.